# combine multi-field html inputs into one argument and pass to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

Trying to work this out, and I've hit a wall.  I'm trying to have html pass the input of multiple fields, which combined equal one string, onto a javascript function.  I started laying it out....then realized I was unsure where to go.  Here is what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particle-api-js/5/particle.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  </script>
<body>

    <p>
    Pump No:<input type="text" id="channel" value="" size="5">
    Time ON:<input type="text" id="onTime" value="" size="8">
    Number of Doses:<input type="text" id="numberOfDoses" value="" size="5">
    Total Dose:<input type="text" id="totalDose" value="" size="5">
    <button onclick="setupChannel()">SET</button>
    </p>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var particle = new Particle();
      var deviceID    = "35002400094734343231xxxx";
      var accessToken = "3aaacdf9121d404c1a60d5f5f853585c156axxxx";
      var fnName = setupChannel;

      function setupChannel(name, argument) {
        var newValue = document.getElementById().value;
        var fnPr = particle.callFunction({
        deviceId: deviceID, name: fnName,argument: fnArg,auth: accessToken
    });
    fnPr.then(function(data) {
        console.log('Function called succesfully:', data);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred:', err);
    });
}
       </script>
```

Comment: why do you have all of your form elements within a single <p> tag? but not within a form? also none of the inputs have a name attribute so you cannot submit the form anyway. and what about validation? empty fields? invalid entry? also be careful with the inputs - when you get them into the js funciton - they will be strings not numbers and so will need conversion into numbers if you want to use them for calculations.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to combine all field values into one string.
do this:

```
<form name="frm">
  <p>
    Pump No:<input type="text" id="channel" value="" size="5">
    Time ON:<input type="text" id="onTime" value="" size="8">
    Number of Doses:<input type="text" id="numberOfDoses" value="" size="5">
    Total Dose:<input type="text" id="totalDose" value="" size="5">
    <button onclick="setupChannel(combineFields())">SET</button>
  </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var particle = new Particle();
  var deviceID    = "35002400094734343231xxxx";
  var accessToken = "3aaacdf9121d404c1a60d5f5f853585c156axxxx";
  var fnName = setupChannel;

  function combineFields() {
    var spacer = " "; // if you want to separate the string elements set spacer to " "  otherwise set spacer to an empty string ("")
    var newValue=""; 
    var elements =document.forms["frm"].elements;
    for(i=0; i<elements.length;i++) {
      newValue+=elements[i].value+spacer;
    };
    return newValue.trim();
  }
  function setupChannel(fields) {
    alert('this is your combined fields into a string: '+fields);
    /// your setup channel code here.
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i would also  do it this way but take care - there is no delimiter in this example, meaning that it would be challenging to determine if "11" was one value of "11" or two values each of "1". I would suggest either a delimiter or simply pushing each value into an array.

Comment: he did not specify that he wanted to distinguish each field in the string.. only that he wanted to combine them.

Comment: ypu i got that - but i also would have specified that there is a limitation in that way of thinking and it could cause issues down the line with interpreting the string. Sorry - I was in a bad mood when I posted that

Comment: your right, I never thought of the fact he might want to break the string back up later on... I'll add a simple space delimiter.

Comment: Thank you both for the help on this.  A couple things, the returned string is showing up with two commas after the last parameter (1,10000,10,100,,) and it shouldn't have any commas.  Lastly, I made some adjustments in an attempt to pass the fields into the particle call function.  I made a fiddle so you can see - https://jsfiddle.net/DustinJB/n39ecq53/#&togetherjs=qgPzuTrJGP

Comment: that why I used spaces... not commas, if  there are extra spaces showing up an the end you can use trim. but yeah, if you go into a complete solution, then the code also has to validate the field make sure they are only numbers, etc. it was not meant to be your full code, only to show you a way to combine them. the rest is up to you... but yeah... modify it. I never thought you would take it as more of an example of ow to combine. OK, good luck with your code.